# Angular JS : Custom validation issue

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set custom validation in my application, and it works for once scenario. When i do focus out or tab out, it works fine. But, i'm handling one more scenario, where while calling a function, from the controller, i'm broadcasting an event and handling it inside the directive. Please find the code snippet :-

**HTML snippet**

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" md-no-float>
  <input type='text' id='signInUsername' ng-model="formData.email" signinauthvalidator name="username" required placeholder="Username ( eg:- bill2016 )">
  <div ng-messages="signInForm.username.$error" class='error-messages'>
    <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>
    <div ng-message="countValidator">Minimum of 4 characters and maximum of 64 is allowed.</div>
    <div ng-message="userExist">User doesn't exist.</div>
  </div>
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container class="md-block" md-no-float>
   <input id='password' signinauthvalidator type="{{si.showpw? 'text': 'password'}}"  placeholder="Password" required name="password" ng-model="formData.password">
   <div ng-messages="signInForm.password.$error" class='error-messages'>
     <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
     <div ng-message="passwordCountValidator">Password should be 8-30 characters</div>
     <div ng-message="passwordInvalid">Invalid password.</div>
   </div>
</md-input-container>
```

**Directive code snippet**

```
scope.$on('authError', function (e,v) {
    if(v == 'PASSWORD_INVALID') {
     ctrl.$setValidity('passwordInvalid', false);
    } else if(v == 'USERNAME_INVALID') {
     ctrl.$setValidity('userExist', false);
    }
});
ctrl.$parsers.push(customValidator);
```

What is happening is, when this code `ctrl.$setValidity('passwordInvalid', false);` executes, this validation is also getting injected to the username field. I checked out the form response and i can see `passwordInvalid` field present in both username and password fields. How can i make this to apply only for password field ? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code for `signinauthvalidator`?

Comment: @31piy Please find the filddle https://jsfiddle.net/cbbau20s/

Comment: I meant a working fiddle, so that I can directly go and check your code for errors.